How to update git in/on Linux openSUSE platform
Which is the latest supported client git version on openSUSE?
I tried to find it in the openSUSE url aka https://software.opensuse.org/ but it only lists available packages without version information. I also tried 'zypper search git' but no version number was presented only package contents. At git site version  2.44.0. is the latest stable.

According to this web page https://software.opensuse.org/package/git-core latest version number is 2.44.0.

You can install git built from source, or via brew package (the easiest way).
